# Wave equation with piecewise (discontinuous) initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have the equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$, with initial conditions $u(0,x)=f(x)=0$ and $u_t(0,x)=g(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & \mbox{if } x>0 \\ 0, & \mbox{if } x \leq 0 \end{cases}$. I have to solve for $x,t\in \mathbb R$.

First, I tried to find the solution for $t>0$. However, when $x+t>0$ and $x-t<0$, $g$ isn't continuous, and d'Alembert's formula yields the (incorrect) solution $u(t,x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+t)$. I've also tried solving for $t>0$ and $x>0$, but I don't think I can find any initial condition $u(t,0)=h(t)$. Am I missing something or should I consider a different approach? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is continuous, and $g$ has discontinuity of the first kind in zero, so we can use d'Alembert's formula: $u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{x-t}^{x+t} g(z) dz = \frac{1}{2} (\int_{x-t}^{0} g(z)dz+\int_{0}^{x+t} g(z)dz)$. In order to calculate this integral we consider three sets:
$$K = \{(t,x)|t>0,x-t<0,x+t<0\}\\
M = \{(t,x)|t>0,x-t<0,x+t>0\}\\
P = \{(t,x)|t>0,x-t>0,x+t>0\}$$

And we obtain
$u(t,x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & (t,x) \in K, \\ 
\frac{x+t}{2}, & (t,x) \in M,  \\ 
t, & (t,x) \in N,
\end{matrix}\right.$

It is easy to prove that $u$ belongs to the class $C([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$. But this functions is not continuously differentiable.

Also, we can prove that this problem has unique solution from class $C([0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Excellent answer, +1. For a new user,  this is neatly written and correct. Can you explain roughly how uniqueness of solution is proved?

Comment: We assume that there are two solutions: $u_1$ and $u_2$, which satisfy Cauchy conditions everywhere and wave equation. For their difference $w=u_1-u_2$ (it is continuous function) we get homogenous Cauchy conditions and homogenous wave equation. This implies $w \equiv 0$, so $u_1 \equiv u_2$.

Comment: Thanks, now I see what my mistake was: for $M$,  $u_t (t,x) = \frac{1}{2}$, which is different from both 0 and 1. What I missed is that in order to calculate the derivative at $(0,x)$ only the solutions in $K$ and $N$ have to be taken into account.

Comment: @jan Thank you for the reply, it is clear now.